# How to import an entity to sugarcrm?

Tags: sugarcrm

When reading an email, there is an Import to Sugar button available on top of the contents. I use izeno SMS module in sugarcrm.

*can I import an SMS and relate it to a contact, account or ... in a systematic way or I should try ugly hard coding stuff?*
*Is Importing a systematic behavior of sugarcrm?* i.e.
*Is importing and relating email imitated anywhere in sugarcrm?*

Answer (score 0):

Importing data into SugarCRM is generally a system-wide ability. Accounts, Contacts, Cases, Calls, Meetings, Leads, etc. can be imported from CSV files. For example, any user with appropriate rights in the system should see the "Import Leads" link in the Leads action list.

See SugarCRM's documentation [Introduction to Importing](http://support.sugarcrm.com/04_Find_Answers/02KB/01Getting_Started/Introduction_to_Importing).

Not all data can be so easily imported. For example, Emails and Contracts cannot be imported via the interface without making code changes. As for [iZeno SMS for SugarCRM](http://www.sugarforge.org/projects/izeno-sms), the [documentation](http://www.sugarforge.org/frs/?group_id=1009) doesn't specifically state whether you can or cannot import SMS data, but being how similar SMS messages to multiple recipients would be to emails, I'd expect it to be difficult. I suggest you contact [iZeno directly](http://www.izeno.com/icontactus) for support and information about their customization.

Comment: thanks, I know sugacrm understands Importing, but in my case it's better to say `importing and relating`. So can I conclude importing and relating email is not imitated anywhere in sugarcrm?

Comment: One to many relationships can be imported when you're talking about accounts and contacts, but emails are a special case altogether. They cannot beer imported through the UI, but can be charged directly in the database. Many to many relationships cannot be imported. So it really depends on how he data is laid out in these modules.